# How do I "orderby" a column without losing posts that don't have the column?

Tags: wp-query

I'm currently using the following code to sort and order my super awesome column that I created:

```
        if ( 'My column' !== $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Order by the _my_column using a numeric interpretation of the value.
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_my_column' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
```

This code gets the job done, but when I click on the column header in order to sort the column, any posts that don't contain that meta field are not included in the listing of posts. I would like to have it such that any posts that don't contain the meta field evaluate as and are sorted as zeroes. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

1. Use the `meta_query` parameter to query both posts that have the metadata `_my_column` (or whatever is the meta key) and posts that do not have it (i.e. does not exist in the database).
2. Use a *custom name* (i.e. array key) with the above meta query clauses and then use the name in the `orderby` parameter.

See [*Query improvements in WP 4.2: ‘orderby’ and ‘meta_query’*](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) for further details.

So instead of using the `meta_key` parameter:

*Note: I see you used `meta_value_num`, so I used the `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` to make sure the meta value is treated as a (signed) integer.*

- If you *don't* want/need to keep existing meta queries (in the `$query` object):

  ```php
  $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
      'relation'             => 'OR',

      // Clause 1, named my_column_exists:
      // Query posts that do have the metadata _my_column.
      'my_column_exists'     => array(
          'key'     => '_my_column', // meta key
          'compare' => 'EXISTS',
          'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      ),

      // Clause 2, named my_column_not_exists:
      // OR that do NOT have the metadata.
      'my_column_not_exists' => array(
          'key'     => '_my_column', // meta key
          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
          'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      ),
  ) );

  $query->set( 'orderby', array(
      // Sort by the _my_column metadata first.
      'my_column_not_exists' => 'DESC',

      // Then if you want, by the post date, title, etc.
      'date'                 => 'ASC',
  ) );
  ```
- Otherwise (to keep existing meta queries), you can do something like:

  ```php
  $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
      // Note: Here the 'relation' defaults to AND.

      // Clause 1, unnamed.
      array(
          'relation'             => 'OR',

          // Sub-clause 1, named my_column_exists:
          // Query posts that do have the metadata _my_column.
          'my_column_exists'     => array(
              'key'     => '_my_column', // meta key
              'compare' => 'EXISTS',
              'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
          ),

          // Sub-clause 2, named my_column_not_exists:
          // OR that do NOT have the metadata.
          'my_column_not_exists' => array(
              'key'     => '_my_column', // meta key
              'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
              'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
          ),
      ),

      // Clause 2, unnamed.
      // Include the existing meta queries.
      (array) $query->get( 'meta_query' ),
  ) );

  $query->set( 'orderby', array(
      // Sort by the _my_column metadata first.
      'my_column_not_exists' => 'DESC',

      // Then if you want, by the post date, title, etc.
      'date'                 => 'ASC',
  ) );
  ```

Comment: This one seems to be 99% there. I'm using the second code, and it's doing exactly what I want except for one single thing. If I click on the column header, it sorts by descending only. So in the URL it says something like ?order=asc or ?order=desc and both return a descending count. How do I get it to do exactly what it's doing except to toggle back and forth based on that? Nevermind. I solved it by adding this:  $order = $query->get('order'); $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'my_column_not_exists' => $order) );