# how to include orderby value that is empty?

Tags: wp-query, sort

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'meta_query' => array(
    array('key' => 'release_date',),)
    ,    'orderby' => 'release_date title','order' => 'DESC',  ) );


query_posts( $args );
```

I'm sorting my post with post that have **release_date** value, however post that don't have **release_date** value are not showing, I wish to add them to the list or do I have to edit all my post to add a value in it? I'm currently using the above code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: May be this will help you a bit : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55791/116990

Comment: You'd want to add a second meta query clause with `compare` set to `NOT EXISTS` - see my answers [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/333794) and/or [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/373496). And please, avoid using [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) - use the `pre_get_posts` hook if you wish to modify the *main WordPress query*.

Comment: @inrsaurabh thank you, i will look into it.

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm just adding additional args for the query post, as I can't find on my themes where the query post, i will check pre_get_posts thank you.

Comment: @SallyCJ the relation and compare works for me, thank you so much.